# Overwriting template Scss variables

Tags: css, sass

I'm using a css template that I bought recently.
This template is provided with scss files. I would like to change the value of a variable in the _vars.scss file.
I was told that it's good practice to not touch the template files and add my changes in another scss file. I tried this but it's not working.

Here is the template main.scss file content:

```scss
@import 'libs/vars';
@import 'libs/functions';
@import 'libs/mixins';
@import 'libs/vendor';
@import 'libs/breakpoints';
@import 'libs/html-grid';
@import 'fontawesome-all.min.css';
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,900,300italic,900italic');

// Breakpoints.

    @include breakpoints((
        xlarge:   ( 1281px,  1680px ),
        large:    ( 981px,   1280px ),
        medium:   ( 737px,   980px  ),
        small:    ( 481px,   736px  ),
        xsmall:   ( 361px,   480px  ),
        xxsmall:  ( null,    360px  )
    ));

// Mixins.

    @mixin color($p) {
        @include color-typography($p);
        @include color-box($p);
        @include color-button($p);
        @include color-form($p);
        @include color-list($p);
        @include color-meta($p);
        @include color-pagination($p);
        @include color-section($p);
        @include color-table($p);
        @include color-posts($p);
    }

// Base.

    @import 'base/reset';
    @import 'base/page';
    @import 'base/typography';

// Component.

    @import 'components/row';
    @import 'components/box';
    @import 'components/button';
    @import 'components/form';
    @import 'components/icon';
    @import 'components/image';
    @import 'components/list';
    @import 'components/actions';
    @import 'components/icons';
    @import 'components/meta';
    @import 'components/pagination';
    @import 'components/section';
    @import 'components/table';
    @import 'components/posts';

// Layout.

    @import 'layout/header';
    @import 'layout/banner';
    @import 'layout/main';
    @import 'layout/footer';
    @import 'layout/navPanel';
```

and here is my custom.scss file content:

```scss
@import '../../template/sass/main';
@import '../../template/css/fontawesome-all.min.css';

@font-face {
    font-family: "Laviossa Medium";
    src: url(../fonts/Laviossa-Medium.otf);
}

$font: ( family-header: ('Laviossa Medium', Helvetica, sans-serif));

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: _font(family-header);
}
```

It's working for the font but not for the palette color.
How can I fix this? Is it possible?